# Doctrine: Check if relation exists for a Discriminator entity

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, query-builder, discriminator

I'm trying to check if a relationship exists or not, in other words, is the column NULL or filled out.

Here I have my QueryBuilder:

```php
$qb->select('v')
    ->from('Entities\Voucher', 'v')
    ->leftJoin('Entities\VoucherCopy', 'vc', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'v.voucherCopy = vc.id')
    ->where("v.code LIKE :voucherCode")
    ->andWhere('vc.id IS NULL');
```

This would be ok if VoucherCopy wasn't Extending "Entities\Codes" - a Single Table Inheritance

VoucherCopy:

```php
class VoucherCopy extends Codes
```

Codes:

```php
/**
 * Entities\DiscountCode
 *
 * @Table(name="discount_code")
 * @Entity()
 *
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"D" = "DiscountCode", "VT" = "PortalVoucher", "V" = "VoucherCopy"})
 */
class Codes
```

**The problem is** that the executed SQL from this query builder is:

```sql
SELECT v0_.*
FROM voucher v0_ 
LEFT JOIN discount_code d1_ ON (
    v0_.discount_code_id = d1_.id
) WHERE (v0_.code LIKE '%DA70511911%' AND d1_.id IS NULL) AND d1_.type IN ('V')
;
```

**Note** the `AND d1_.type IN ('V')`.  This is because DQL is automatically adding this because it knows that's the discriminator column for this Entity, but in doing so `AND d1_.id IS NULL` becomes redundant as I can't check if the relationship fails with the `AND d1_.type IN ('V')` check.

Is checking if a relationship exists whilst using single table inheritance possible?

I've tried leftJoin to Entities\Code (the parent) directly, but I can't add the discriminator column (type) as a property because you get error: Duplicate definition of column 'type' on entity 'Entities\Codes' in a field or discriminator column mapping.